# Dump .onion using lynx in bash

Tags: tor, lynx

So, I set up a Tor socks proxy on my machine, and I want to use proxychains or some alternative to have lynx dump links from a Tor .onion site. I tested to see if the proxy works and noted that I can connect to the site in Firefox using Foxyproxy, and it seems to work. But, if I try setting Proxychains to use the proxy, it seems the proxy is working as my IP was different when I ran this command:

`proxychains curl ipecho.net/plain;echo`

However, lynx gave search results instead of dumping the links when I ran:

```
proxychains lynx -dump "$site" |awk '/http/{print $2}'
```

I am guessing maybe it is because it is using my actual DNS rather than the DNS on the proxy. I also tried tsocks and got this error:

```
14:24:33 libtsocks(31636): Error 114 attempting to connect to SOCKS server (Operation already in progress)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `torsocks` instead of `proxychains`. For instance: `torsocks curl https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/` will get the duck duck go .onion site homepage. You also don't have to echo it out, it prints it to the terminal by default.